# Open JFileChooser on doubleclick of JTable

Tags: mouseevent, jfilechooser, double-click

I have another question.

I want to open a JFileChooser window when I double click on a JTable. 
My code so far :

```
productTable.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
        public void dblclick(MouseEvent click){
            if (click.getClickCount() == 2){
                fileChooser.setVisible(true);
        }
        }
    });
```

I have fileChooser declared as a new JFileChooser box, to clear up any confusion. I kind of understand ActionListeners but my understanding is really only limited to regular buttons. I read through mouse listeners, and the code above is my understanding.

How do I add the class dblclick on double click of the JTable?

Also, if there is an easier way to approach the problem, I would greatly appreciate some pointers.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I actually figured out my own problem.. Again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I actually figured it out on my own... As I figured, it was a pretty simple solution.

I changed the above code to :

```
productTable.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent click){
            productTableMouseClicked(click);
        }
    });
```

and then I added the handler at the bottom with my other action handlers :

```
 private void productTableMouseClicked(MouseEvent click){
    if (click.getClickCount() == 2){
        fileChooser.showOpenDialog(fileChooser);
    }
}
```

So that's that, I guess.